NiceMatrix + Tikz Determinants Picture
I'm having trouble recreating a particular picture I want to use. It's a 3 x 3 determinants formula, which I'm trying to use the nodes created by NiceMatrix to create loops around the entries to highlight the multiplications. 
I created the following, in an attempt to recreate it, but it looks awful, as the lines aren't parallel. I assumed the nodes would be in the same place for each entry.
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,gensymb,textcomp,enumitem,graphicx,tikz,nicematrix}
    \def\arraystretch{1.25} 
\begin{center} \begin{NiceTabular}{|ccc|cc}
   $a$  & $b$ &  $c$ & $a$ &  $b$ \\ 
    $d$ & $e$ &  $f$ & $d$ & $e$ \\
    $g$ & $h$ & $i$ & $g$ & $h$ 
    \CodeAfter 
    \tikz
      \draw[red]
         (1-1.south west) -- (3-3.south west)
         (1-1.north east) -- (3-3.north east)
         (1-1.south west) arc (225:43:4pt) -- (1-1.north east)
         (3-3.south west) arc (225:407:4.1pt) -- (3-3.north east);
        \tikz
      \draw[red]
         (1-2.south west) -- (3-4.south west)
         (1-2.north east) -- (3-4.north east)
         (1-2.south west) arc (225:63:4.8pt)
         (3-4.south west) arc (225:407:4.7pt) -- (3-4.north east);
    \tikz
      \draw[red]
         (1-3.south west) -- (3-5.south west)
         (1-3.north east) -- (3-5.north east)
         (1-3.south west) arc (225:45:4.7pt) -- (1-3.north east)
         (3-5.south west) arc (225:407:5.2pt) -- (3-5.north east);
    \tikz
      \draw[blue]
         (3-1.south east) -- (1-3.south east)
         (3-1.north west) -- (1-3.north west)
         (3-1.north west) arc (135:315:4.7pt)
         (1-3.north west) arc (135:-20:5.3pt);
     \tikz
      \draw[blue]
         (3-2.south east) -- (1-4.south east)
         (3-2.north west) -- (1-4.north west)
         (3-2.north west) arc (135:315:5.2pt)
         (1-4.north west) arc (135:-25:4.4pt);
\end{NiceTabular} \end{center}}
\end{document}

Which produced this:

I don't really know how to proceed except to do it by coordinates, which would be very time consuming. Thanks for your help.

A solution with pic
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
$
\begin{NiceArray}{*{5}{>{\mathstrut}c}}[columns-width=7mm, cell-space-limits=5pt]
    \CodeBefore [create-cell-nodes]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[pics/mf/.style n args={3}{code={
            \path (#1.center) -- (#2.center) --
                ([turn]0:\lin) -- ([turn]90:\lw) coordinate (f1);
            \path (#1.center) -- (#2.center) --
                ([turn]0:\lin) -- ([turn]-90:\lw) coordinate (f2);
            \path (#2.center) -- (#1.center) --
                ([turn]0:\lin) -- ([turn]90:\lw) coordinate (f3);
            \path (#2.center) -- (#1.center) --
                ([turn]0:\lin) -- ([turn]-90:\lw) coordinate (f4);
            \draw[#3, rounded corners=\lw]
                (f1) -- (f2) -- (f3) -- (f4) -- cycle;
        }}]
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\lin}{3mm}
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\lw}{2mm}
        \pic {mf={3-1}{1-3}{red,dashed}};
        \pic {mf={3-2}{1-4}{red}};
        \pic {mf={3-3}{1-5}{red}};
        \pic {mf={1-1}{3-3}{blue}};
        \pic {mf={1-2}{3-4}{blue}};
        \pic {mf={1-3}{3-5}{blue}};
        \draw[thick] (1 -| 1) -- (last -| 1) (1 -| 4) -- (last -| 4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \Body
    a & b & c & a & b \\
    d & e & f & d & e \\
    g & h & i & g & h \\
\end{NiceArray}
$
\end{document}



Just for fun and learning, an option using tikz matrix, then through code nested in definitions with parameters, taking advantage of the calc library you can obtain the angle between 2 points, then through this angle draw what you want using this value, in this case the mark as a determinant.
The advantage in definitios is that the parameters can be configured in more flexible format, such as for example in the first one in [] delimeters just adding some text to indicate what each variable is. \Det[color #1 size #2 line #3] ...
Also I use positioning so that the matrices can be placed next to each other in addition to giving them names, not to be confused with the M style, which ensures that the nodes are math nodes fot math text type and that they have a uniform size that does not is affected unless the internal text exceeds this value minimum size=1.75em.
The formula is also defined in a matrix but the separation between columns is modified column sep=-0.5em so that it looks closer together than normal, so since it is a matrix you can also reach each part using their matrix names. (Matrix_name-Col_index-file_index)
Also, to make everything fit, it is good to use a single type of unit in this case because it is relative to the size of the fonts, for that reason you can see a more controlled result.
RESULT:

MWE:
\documentclass[border=14pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,gensymb} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,calc}
\definecolor{COLOR1}{HTML}{6B99B9}
\definecolor{COLOR2}{HTML}{DD9CC4}
\tikzset{
    M/.style={
        matrix of math nodes,
        nodes={draw=none,anchor=center,minimum size=1.75em},
        nodes in empty cells,
    }
}

%Drawing code nesting in definition with parameters
\def\Det[color #1 size #2 line #3]#4#5{
    \draw[line width=#3,draw=#1, opacity=0.7]
    let \p1 = ($(#5)-(#4)$), % To access cartesian coordinates x, and y.
        \n2 = {atan2(\x1,\y1)}, % to get the angle of the line betwen #5 to #4
    in
    (#5.center)
        ++(90-\n2+90:#2/2) 
        arc (90-\n2+90:90-\n2+90-180:#2/2)
        -- ($(#4.center)+(90-\n2-90:#2/2)$)
        arc (90-\n2-90:90-\n2-90-180:#2/2)
        -- cycle;
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix[M] at (0,0) (M1){ % Matrix contents  
            a & b & c  \\
            d & e & f  \\
            g & h & i  \\
        };
    
        \node[right=0em of M1](EQ){$=$};    
        \matrix[M,right=0em of EQ](M2){ % Matrix contents  
            a & b & c & a & b \\
            d & e & f & d & e \\
            g & h & i & g & h \\
        };
        \matrix[M,right=-1em of M2,column sep=-0.5em,](M3){ % Matrix contents  
            = & (aei & + & bfg & + & cdh) & - & (gec & + & hfa & + & idb)\\
        };
    
        \foreach \a/\b/\c in {M1/1/west,M1/3/east,M2/1/west,M2/4/west}{\draw(\a-1-\b.north \c) -- (\a-3-\b.south \c);}
        \Det[color blue,dashed size 1em line 0.5pt]{M1-1-1}{M1-3-3} % test
        \Det[color blue,dashed size 0.5em line 0.5pt]{M1-1-3}{M1-3-2} %test
        \Det[color COLOR1 size 1.25em line 0.8pt]{M2-1-1}{M2-3-3}
        \Det[color COLOR1 size 1.25em line 0.8pt]{M2-1-2}{M2-3-4}
        \Det[color COLOR1 size 1.25em line 0.8pt]{M2-1-3}{M2-3-5}
        \Det[color COLOR2 size 1.25em line 0.8pt]{M2-3-1}{M2-1-3}
        \Det[color COLOR2 size 1.25em line 0.8pt]{M2-3-2}{M2-1-4}
        \Det[color COLOR2 size 1.25em line 0.8pt]{M2-3-3}{M2-1-5}
        \draw[COLOR1,->](M2-3-3)++(0,-1.25em/2)--++(0,-1em)-|(M3-1-2);
        \draw[COLOR1,->](M2-3-4)++(0,-1.25em/2)--++(0,-1.5em)-|(M3-1-4);
        \draw[COLOR1,->](M2-3-5)++(0,-1.25em/2)--++(0,-2em)-|(M3-1-6);
        \draw[COLOR2,->](M2-1-3)++(0,1.25em/2)--++(0,1em)-|(M3-1-8);
        \draw[COLOR2,->](M2-1-4)++(0,1.25em/2)--++(0,1.5em)-|(M3-1-10);
        \draw[COLOR2,->](M2-1-5)++(0,1.25em/2)--++(0,2em)-|(M3-1-12);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

