Draw a mnemonic device of the determinant of a 3-by-3 matrix with TikZ
I would like to draw a mnemonic device of the determinant of a 3-by-3 matrix with TikZ.
Here is what I want to draw. I made this figure by GeoGebra (https://www.geogebra.org/m/ukmwbtev). It might be noted that the entries of the 3-by-3 matrix (and the six nomials of the determinant) are actually not perfectly placed.

I am sorry that I cannot give a minimal working example now; I am still a beginner of TikZ.
Thanks.

Welcome. // I suggest to peek into https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=Determinant. Either you‘ll find a solution you like even more, or you can use some modified code to start with, and add to your question.

E.g., what do you think of the solutions to this question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/722558/nicematrix-tikz-determinants-picture

@MS-SPO Thanks for your advice. // I guess that I might be able to learn something from the solutions to the question that you mentioned, and of course, from the solutions of other similar questions.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@Juliamisto  The easiest way, in my opinion, is to use a TikZ matrix. First you write everything in your cells and then draw the lines as annotation. "Laborious task"...

@cis Thanks for your advice. // The task is indeed laborious; it even took me much time to draw the figure with GeoGebra as well.

While this is a nice picture, don't you think that images like https://cdn1.byjus.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/maths/2015/12/24070546/Determinant-Of-A-Matrix.jpg are better mnemonic devices, where you just copy the matrix?

@gernot I agree that the mnemonic device that you suggested is better than the mnemonic device that this question concerns. The one that you suggested is easier.
